# How do I control the armature in weight paint mode?

Tags: weight-painting

When in weight paint mode when I right click a bone it goes into object mode and selects the whole armature but what I want to do is manipulate the bones while in paint mode, as seen in tutorials, to either move a part out of the way or test the weight painting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The armature has to be in *Pose* mode, then Shift-select the mesh and go into *Weight Paint* mode.

If you have selection set to *Right-click* in *Preferences* then:

- Sample weight (color) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>LMB</kbd>
- Select bone with <kbd>RMB</kbd>

If you have selection set to *Left-click* in *Preferences*:

- Sample weight (color) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>RMB</kbd>
- Select bone with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>LMB</kbd>

Independently of *Select with* option:

- Paint with <kbd>LMB</kbd>
- Rotate, Move, Scale bone with <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>
- Paint gradient with <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>LMB</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I managed to enable the bone selection in *Weight Paint Mode* only after selecting both mesh and armature in *Object Mode* (the mesh should be selected second). Then switch from *Object Mode* to *Weight Paint Mode* and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> to select the bone.